# loading images from webserver

Tags: android, mysql, image

I wrote an app which loads datas (text and images) from a MYSQL DB from a webserver. In the emulator the program works fine. Then I tried it with my native device HTC in the 'debug as' modus. Still fine. But when I unplug the device and run it standalone the images are not being loaded anymore. 
The 'funny' thing is, that I have one image called 'default.jpg' it is in the same folder as all the other images which are called like 'AB-123_1.jpg. The 'default.jpg' is the only image which loads also in the 'standalone' modus. I also gave it a try with renaming the images to some simple names like blabla.jpg. But it did not helped.

It's my first app, so maybe I just missed something.

Answer (score 0):

The only real suggestions I can make are:

1. Pop up an alert in the catch poriton of your exception handling
2. Look into using [traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) - not sure if it will help here, as I've only ever used it for profiling
3. According to [Redirect Log output to sdcard on customer's phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640708/redirect-log-output-to-sdcard-on-customers-phone), the app Catalog may be of some use (not tried it)
4. Try doing a clean build and uninstalling your app from the phone first, just in case of weirdness with code not rebuilding properly

Just to rule out the obvious (which should break debug builds anyway), but did you specify

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've uninstalled all previous versions before I've installed the new one. The permission is set. (As you said, I would not be able to run it in debug mode. And I get all text datas (and the default.jpg) from the server with no problems.)

Comment: I'll try with the trace and/or pop ups. At the moment I get 'permission denied' when trying to start the trace...  I've found some articles concerning the permission problem. Looks like I have to dig deeper into it. (sigh) In case someone has an idea in which direction I need to look.... I would be thankful.

Comment: Do you have access to the server request logs? Just in case there's some unexpected corruption of the request URLs? At the very least, it would be useful to find out if the requests make it through to the server. It's also worth verifying there's no difference in the response data (assuming there's some kind of markup listing the images).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the logs. It's on my providers server and I only have very restricted access. But I found out, that it probably has to do with the size of the pictures. If I make them smaller it works. What is really strange, because the original images where between 50-100 kb. With a size between 5-10 kb it works. But they are really small now. Does anyone knows if there is a size limit? I know, the smaller the better, but it should also be kind of interesting to look at them....